# What's a suitable data type?

Tags: haskell, monads

In the question, [Seeking constructive criticism on monad implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765260/criticize-simple-monad), [abesto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/583780/abesto) asked people to criticize his "Monad" which kept count of the number of bind operations. It turned out that this was not actually a monad because it did not satisfy the first two monadic laws, but I found the example interesting. Is there any data type that would be suitable for such kinds of structures?

Comment: What kinds of structures?  A monad-that-violates-the-first-two-laws is a "suitable" structure for that idea.  But without more constraints it is hard to know what you are asking.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's an interesting question, and has to do with the mathematical lineage of monads.

We could certainly create a typeclass called something like `Monadish`, which would look exactly like the `Monad` typeclass:

```
class Monadish m where
  returnish :: a -> m a
  bindish :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

So the monad laws have nothing to do with the actual signature of the typeclass; they're extra information that an implementor has to enforce by themselves. So, in one sense, the answer is "of course"; just make another typeclass and say it doesn't have to satisfy any laws.

But is such a typeclass interesting? For a mathematician, the answer would be **no**: the lack of any laws means that there is no interesting *structure* by which to reason with. When we define a mathematical structure, we usually define some objects (check), some operations (check) and then some properties of the operations (...nope). We need all three of these to prove theorems about this class of objects, and, to take one example, abstract algebra is all about taking the same operations and adding more or fewer laws.

For a software engineer, the answer is a little more complex.  Reasoning is not required: you can always just use a typeclass to overload syntax for your own nefarious purposes. We can use a typeclass to group things together that "feel" the same, even though we don't have any formal reasons for believing so. There are some benefits to doing this, but I personally feel this throws out a lot of the benefits of having laws, and leads to architecture astronauts who invent abstract structures without a whole lot of thought of their applicability. Maths is a safer bet: the monad laws correspond to left identity, right identity, and associativity, reasonably fundamental assumptions that even a non-mathematical person would be familiar with.

Comment: No decent Haskell compiler relies on the monad laws being obeyed by a Monad instance, since the compiler cannot verify them.  So we don't need Monadish; we have it already.

Comment: It's crucial to be able to have monad instances that do not satisfy the monad laws when doing DSELs.  The do notation can be used for all kinds of things, and the monad laws are often broken by those instances.  (The monad laws might hold on a deeper level, but not at the Haskell level.)

Comment: This is a very good answer, thanks. I was aware that the Monad typeclass would work fine, but I was wondering whether there exists another mathematical structure, captured by some typeclass, whose properties would be satisfied by the example of counting binding operations.

Comment: augustss: I think there are cases where rewrite rules could rely on laws being obeyed by a particular piece of code, although I don't think there are any such rules for monad.

Comment: donquixote: Are you talking about a different signature? The usual way to go about doing this is define some other operation, and then show that all of the original operations can be defined in terms of this operation, and vice-versa, and that all the laws continue to be preserved. For example, you can replace bind with `join :: m (m a) -> m a` (exercise!)