# Is it possible to create a Monad that count the number of instructions?

Tags: haskell, monads

Thinking about monad, it came to me the idea of a monad as the way to break with the Von Neumann architecture. The Von Neumann architecture uses a set of instructions (called program) to change the data in memory and the execution of each instruction of the program updates a program counter to know whom instruction is the next to execute.

If we think about the Von Neumann architecture as a monad, the bind operator (>>=) update the program counter. We can make a Monad that break Von Neumann architecture to do more in the bind. As an example, we can have a Monad that count the number of instructions executed in our programs.

But, when I tried to implement that Monad in haskell as:

```
data Counter a = Counter Integer a
             deriving( Show )

instance Monad Counter where
  (Counter n1 a) >>= f = let Counter _ b = f a
                     in (Counter (n1+1) b)
  return a = Counter 1 a
```

I notice it'll break de Monads laws, e.g:

```
return x >>= f            /=   f x

do
   a <- return 3
   return a

do 
   return 3
```

The two blocks are the same because the monad laws, but they'll return something different because they have different number of instructions (sentences)

Do I made something wrong? or Is it not possible to have such Monad?

Comment: This is a good question, could you rewrite to make it more clear?  It's a little hard to read because of the errors.

Comment: Well, it seems that it would not break that laws, if `return`s do not count.

Comment: @Matt Fenwick, I rewrite the question to fix grammar.

Comment: @FUZxxl, I don't see how to init the counter without return

Comment: @Zhen Well, the only thing I suggest is to stops  `return`s and `>>=`s changing the counter. (So `return` returns `0` and `f >>= g` returns `counter f + gounter g`). Then, all the monad laws are obeyed. If you want to have something counted as an operation, you could instead use an operation similar to `return` called `op` that counts as `1`. As the monad laws do not treat `op` specially, they won't interfer with `op`. Also, this way you get a clear distinction between things that "count" and things that don't "count".

Comment: I think the formulation suggested by @fuz above is equivalent to `Writer (Sum Int)`. Each value has a counter attached to it, and combining operations sums their counters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Strictly speaking, any such "monad" breaks the monad laws and is thus... not a monad.  See this [previous question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765260/criticize-simple-monad).  In other words - your guess is correct, it is not possible to have such a monad.

Answer (score 3):

As another answer already mentioned, no lawful monad can count just the number of binds. But there is a way to count a related quantity: the number of binds minus the number of returns. This is still useful since it lets you count the number of nontrivial monadic operations.

```hs
instance Functor Counter where
    fmap f (Counter n x) = Counter n (f x)

instance Applicative Counter where
    pure = Counter (-1)
    Counter n1 f <*> Counter n2 x = Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) (f x)

instance Monad Counter where
    Counter n1 a >>= f = let Counter n2 b = f a in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
    return = Counter (-1)
```

Here's some quick justifications for why this is lawful:

```
-- left identity
return x >>= f = f x
Counter (-1) x >>= f = f x
let Counter n2 b = f x in Counter ((-1) + n2 + 1) b = f x
let Counter n2 b = f x in Counter n2 b = f x
f x = f x

-- right identity
m >>= return = m
Counter n1 a >>= return = Counter n1 a
let Counter n2 b = return a in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b = Counter n1 a
let Counter n2 b = Counter (-1) a in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b = Counter n1 a
Counter (n1 + (-1) + 1) a = Counter n1 a
Counter n1 a = Counter n1 a

-- associativity
m >>= f >>= g = m >>= \x -> f x >>= g
Counter n1 a >>= f >>= g = Counter n1 a >>= \x -> f x >>= g
(let Counter n2 b = f a in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b) >>= g = Counter n1 a >>= \x -> f x >>= g
(let Counter n2 b = f a in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b) >>= g = let Counter n2 b = (\x -> f x >>= g) a in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
(let Counter n2 b = f a in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b) >>= g = let Counter n2 b = f a >>= g in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a in (Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b >>= g) = let Counter n2 b = f a >>= g in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a in (let Counter n3 c = g b in Counter ((n1 + n2 + 1) + n3 + 1) c) = let Counter n2 b = f a >>= g in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a in (let Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c) = let Counter n2 b = f a >>= g in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a; Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c = let Counter n2 b = f a >>= g in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a; Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c = let Counter n2 b = (let Counter n3 c = f a in Counter n3 c) >>= g in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a; Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c = let Counter n2 b = (let Counter n3 c = f a in Counter n3 c >>= g) in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a; Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c = let Counter n2 b = (let Counter n3 c = f a in (let Counter n4 d = g c in Counter (n3 + n4 + 1) d)) in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a; Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c = let Counter n2 b = (let Counter n3 c = f a; Counter n4 d = g c in Counter (n3 + n4 + 1) d) in Counter (n1 + n2 + 1) b
let Counter n2 b = f a; Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c = let Counter n3 c = f a; Counter n4 d = g c in Counter (n1 + (n3 + n4 + 1) + 1) d
let Counter n2 b = f a; Counter n3 c = g b in Counter (n1 + n2 + n3 + 2) c = let Counter n3 c = f a; Counter n4 d = g c in Counter (n1 + n3 + n4 + 2) d
```

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation throws away the number of steps in f. Shouldn't you add them?

```
  (Counter n1 a) >>= f = let Counter n2 b = f a
                     in (Counter (n1+n2) b)
```

Comment: You are right, but it don't fix the monad laws. It should be (n1+n2+1).