# Maybe-like monad that gives breadcrumbs when Nothing occurs

Tags: haskell

I have two record types

```
data OptionalRecord = OptionalRecord
  { mFoo :: Maybe Foo
  , mBar :: Maybe Bar
  , mBaz :: Maybe Baz
  }

data RequiredRecord = RequiredRecord
  { foo :: Foo
  , bar :: Bar
  , baz :: Baz
  }
```

I have a function:

```
optionalToRequired :: OptionalRecord -> Maybe RequiredRecord
optionalToRequired OptionalRecord{..} =
  do
    foo <- mFoo
    bar <- mBar
    baz <- mBaz
    return RequiredRecord{..}
```

This funcion works fine, but when it returns `Nothing`, I don't have any info about which field (or line in the `do` block) was `Nothing`.
Does anyone have any suggestions for an alternative that includes more info, like line number, that doesn't require a lot of embellishment?

Comment: `Either` is normally used to return an error message: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is it possible to collect all error messages in the Either Monad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63346279/how-is-it-possible-to-collect-all-error-messages-in-the-either-monad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

William's suggestion in the comments is a good one: if you use Either instead of Maybe, then instead of Nothing, your computations can produce information about why they failed. But you do have to provide this information: you can't just get it automatically from the compiler with a line number for the bind. Indeed you can't introduce *any* information with a bind that doesn't come from the monadic value being binded, because this would break the Monad laws.

A common example of this is "What if I could count how many calls to `>>=` (or uses of `<-` in do-notation) there have been?". You can see why that doesn't work in the question [Is it possible to create a Monad that count the number of instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956668/is-it-possible-to-create-a-monad-that-count-the-number-of-instructions).

Answer (score 1):

As others have stated, `Either a` meets the requirements you've mentioned, but there is a very good reason for this: `Either a` behaves the same as `Maybe` as a `Monad`.

1. It can only hold a single value or no values.
2. An "error" value (`Left foo` or `Nothing`) short-circuits further computations whereas a "success" value (`Right bar` or `Just bar`) does not. (This means that you can only use `Right` as an indication of success and `Left` as an indication of an error.)
3. You can pattern-match "error" and "success" values at the end.

There is a large variety of `Monad` semantics out there, and having the concept of an error message isn't alone sufficient to take the place of `Maybe`.