# Making Haskell Monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm trying to create a very simple monad in Haskell.
The monad does nothing special but holding a counter as state.

```
module EmptyMonad
  ( EmptyMonad
  ) where

import Control.Monad

data EmptyMonad a = EmptyMonad
  { myValue :: a
  , myState :: Int
  } deriving (Show)

instance (Eq a) => Eq (EmptyMonad a) where
  EmptyMonad x1 y1 == EmptyMonad x2 y2 = x1 == x2 && y1 == y2


instance Monad (EmptyMonad a) where
  return x = EmptyMonad x 0
  (EmptyMonad x y) >>= f = EmptyMonad x (y + 1)
```

After spending few hours on Monads, I cannot get my head around the error from the compiler:

```
EmptyMonad.hs:16:10: error:
    • Expecting one fewer argument to ‘Monad EmptyMonad’
      Expected kind ‘k0 -> Constraint’,
        but ‘Monad EmptyMonad’ has kind ‘Constraint’
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Monad EmptyMonad a’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Comment: You should write `instance Monad EmptyMonad where` (without `a`).

Comment: Furthermore it should be `(EmptyMonad x y) >>= f = EmptyMonad (f x) (y + 1)`. (with `f`), otherwise the types do not match.

Comment: I get this error if I follow your suggestion, no idea.
 Couldn't match type ‘b’ with ‘EmptyMonad b’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          (>>=) :: forall a b.
                   EmptyMonad a -> (a -> EmptyMonad b) -> EmptyMonad b
        at EmptyMonad.hs:18:20

Comment: what if you follow the second suggestion as well?

Comment: I applied both of the suggestions.

Comment: I would advise you to read [**Kinds and some type-foo**](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#kinds-and-some-type-foo) and [**Making monads**](http://learnyouahaskell.com/for-a-few-monads-more#making-monads)

Comment: As a complete aside to your problems understanding and using Haskell syntax, you are also going to have a semantic problem. Counting binds is not okay in monads; it violates the "`return` is an identity" law saying that `return x >>= f = f x`, since there are fewer binds on the right-hand side of the equation. (It seems to be everybody's first idea for a new monad, though, including mine!)

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765260/seeking-constructive-criticism-on-monad-implementation) which asks about a "counter monad" also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main problems here:

- the instance declaration does *expect* a type of *kind* `* -> *`. So for instance `[]`, *not* `[a]`; and
- the bind operator `>>=` expect an `EmptyMonad a`, and a function `a -> EmptyMonad b` and returns an `EmptyMonad b` element.

So we can fix the problems with the following solution:

```
instance Monad EmptyMonad where  -- no a after EmptyMonad
  return x = EmptyMonad x 0
  (EmptyMonad x y) >>= f = fx {myState = y+1}
      where fx = f x
```

So here we specify `instance Monad EmptyMonad` since `EmptyMonad` has kind `* -> *`. Furthermore the bind operator will calculate `f x` and then alter the `myState` of that instance with `y+1`.

That being said, nowadays you need to make `EmptyMonad` an instance of `Applicative` and `Functor` as well.

Comment: Why can't I use `EmptyMonad fx (y+1)` instead of `fx {myState = y+1}`?

Comment: @user1 Because `fx` is an `EmptyMonad b`, not a `b`. So `EmptyMonad fx (y+1)` would be an `EmptyMonad (EmptyMonad b)` -- a nested monadic value!