# Generating a unique value in Haskell do-notation

Tags: haskell, monads, state-monad, do-notation

To generate x86 assembly code, I have defined a custom type called `X86`:

```
data X86 a = X86 { code :: String, counter :: Integer, value :: (X86 a -> a) }
```

This type is used in do-notation like the following. This makes it easy to write templates for generating if-statements, for-loops, etc...

```
generateCode :: X86 ()
generateCode = do
  label1 <- allocateUniqueLabel
  label2 <- allocateUniqueLabel
  jmp label1
  label label1
  jmp label2
  label label2
```

Instructions are defined like this:

```
jmp :: String -> X86 ()
jmp l = X86 { code = "jmp " ++ l ++ ";\n", counter = 0, value = const () }

label :: String -> X86 ()
label l = X86 { code = l ++ ":\n", counter = 0, value = const () }
```

And the completed assembly file is printed like so:

```
printAsm :: X86 a -> String
printAsm X86{code=code} = code

main = do
  putStrLn (printAsm generateCode)
```

I implemented the `X86` monad in the following manner. Essentially, the sequence operator concatenates blocks of assembly code in order and ensures the counters are incremented.

```
instance Monad X86 where
  x >> y = X86 { code = code x ++ code y, counter = counter x + counter y, value = value y }
  x >>= f = x >> y
    where y = f (value x x)
```

The problem is the labels are not incremented properly, so they are not unique! The following is the output:

```
jmp Label1;
Label1:
jmp Label1;
Label1:
```

I desire the output to have a unique value for each label:

```
jmp Label1;
Label1:
jmp Label2;
Label2:
```

To complete the example, here is the implementation of the `allocatedUniqueLabel` function:

```
allocateUniqueId :: X86 Integer
allocateUniqueId = X86 { code = "", counter = 1, value = counter }

allocateUniqueLabel :: X86 String
allocateUniqueLabel = do
  id <- allocateUniqueId
  return ("Label" ++ show id)
```

How can I fix my `X86` monad so the labels are unique?

**Here is what I've tried:**

- Incrementing a global counter. => Haskell does not safely allow global state outside the IO monad.
- Using the `State` monad. => I have looked into a number of examples, but do not understand how to integrate them into my existing `X86` monad.
- Keep track of the counter outside of the monad. => I rather the counter is updated "behind the scenes"; otherwise, a lot of code templates which do not use labels will need to propagate the counter manually.

Comment: Are you just using the `Monad` class as a convenience or is there somehow a lawful instance?

Comment: @Li-yaoXia It's used mainly to create a DSL via do-notation. Whether the instance is lawful, I am not entirely sure, but it has been working successfully up until the point where unique labels were needed.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure whether I was missing something, but `X86` is in fact not even a `Functor` (which a `Monad` would have to be).

Comment: you could try to implement State yourself, to get more idea of it. Basically, its `counter`'s type should be rather `Integer -> Integer`

Comment: A minor suggestion: I'd create a dedicated `Label` type for the result of `allocateUniqueLabel`. This will make your code a bit safer, making sure you only jump to labels, not arbitrary strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use [mtl classes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl) to describe X86 code as effectful programs. We want:

- to generate code, this is a `Writer` effect;
- to maintain a counter, this is a `State` effect.

We worry about instantiating these effects last, and in the description of the programs we use `MonadWriter` and `MonadState` constraints.

```
import Control.Monad.State  -- mtl
import Control.Monad.Writer
```

Allocating a new identifier increments the counter, without generating any code. This only uses the `State` effect.

```
type Id = Integer

allocateUniqueLabel :: MonadState Id m => m String
allocateUniqueLabel = do
  i <- get
  put (i+1)  -- increment
  return ("Label" ++ show (i+1))
```

And of course, we have actions to generate code, that don't need to care about the current state. So they use the `Writer` effect.

```
jmp :: MonadWriter String m => String -> m ()
jmp l = tell ("jmp " ++ l ++ ";\n")

label :: MonadWriter String m => String -> m ()
label l = tell (l ++ ":\n")
```

The actual program looks the same as the original, but with more general types.

```
generateCode :: (MonadState Id m, MonadWriter String m) => m ()
generateCode = do
  label1 <- allocateUniqueLabel
  label2 <- allocateUniqueLabel
  jmp label1
  label label1
  jmp label2
  label label2
```

The effects are instantiated when we run this program, here using `runWriterT`/`runWriter` and `runStateT`/`runState` (the order doesn't matter much, these two effects commute).

```
type X86 = WriterT String (State Id)

runX86 :: X86 () -> String
runX86 gen = evalState (execWriterT gen) 1 -- start counting from 1
-- evalState and execWriterT are wrappers around `runStateT` and `runWriterT`:
-- - execWriterT: discards the result (of type ()), only keeping the generated code.
-- - evalState: discards the final state, only keeping the generated code,
--   and does some unwrapping after there are no effects to handle.
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use this monad stack:

```
type X86 a = StateT Integer (Writer String) a
```

Since you have a state and a writer, you could also consider using `RWS` (reader-writer-state all in one):

```
type X86 a = RWS () String Integer a
```

Let's pick the first one for fun.  I'd first define a helper function to increment the counter ([monads cannot lawfully increment a counter "automatically"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4765260/seeking-constructive-criticism-on-monad-implementation/4765447#4765447)):

```
instr :: X86 a -> X86 a
instr i = do
    x <- i
    modify (+1)
    return x
```

Then you could define `jmp` as:

```
jmp :: String -> X86 ()
jmp l = instr $ do
    lift (tell ("jmp " ++ l ++ ";\n"))
       -- 'tell' is one of Writer's operations, and then we 'lift'
       -- it into StateT
```

(The `do` there is superfluous, however I suspect there will be a pattern of starting instruction definitions with `instr $ do`)

I would *not* roll my own monad for this -- it can be instructive to do so, but I think you'll get more mileage using the standard libraries for this one.

Comment: Why do we need to increment the label counter for `jmp`? I'd say it's only necessary to do so when generating a new label (unless we want to assign an unique identifier to each instruction in a piece of code, which would be a different problem).

Answer (score 3):

As you probably now underestand from the other answers, the problem with your
approach was that even though you were using the counter, you were still
generating your labels locally. In particular

```
label1 <- allocateUniqueLabel
label label1
```

was equivalent to

```
X86 { code = "Label1:\n", counter = 1, value = const () }
```

We need to assemble the whole code first, generate the labels, and only
afterwards (in some sense) generate the actual code using the labels.
And this is what the other answers are suggesting by having the counter stored
in the `State` (or `RWS`) monad.

---

There is yet another issue that we can address: You want to be able to jump both
forwards and backwards. This is most likely why you have separate
`allocateUniqueLabel` and `label` functions. But this allows to set the same
label twice.

It is actually possible to use to `do` notation with "backwards" binding using
[`MonadFix`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fix.html#t:MonadFix),
which defines this monadic operation:

```
mfix :: (a -> m a) -> m a
```

Since both `State` and `RWS` have `MonadFix` instances, we can indeed write code
like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, RecursiveDo #-}
module X86
    ( X86()
    , runX86
    , label
    , jmp
    ) where

import Control.Monad.RWS

-- In production code it'll be much faster if we replace String with
-- ByteString.
newtype X86 a = X86 (RWS () String Int a)
    deriving (Functor, Applicative, Monad, MonadFix)

runX86 :: X86 a -> String
runX86 (X86 k) = snd (execRWS k () 1)

newtype Label = Label { getLabel :: String }

label :: X86 Label
label = X86 $ do
    counter <- get
    let l = "Label" ++ show counter
    tell (l ++ ":\n")
    modify (+1)
    return (Label l)

jmp :: Label -> X86 ()
jmp (Label l) = X86 . tell $ "jmp " ++ l ++ ";\n"
```

And use it like this:

```
example :: X86 ()
example = do
    rec l1 <- label
        jmp l2
        l2 <- label
    jmp l1
```

There are a few things to note:

- We need to use the `RecursiveDo` extension to enable the `rec` keyword.
- Keyword `rec` delimits a block of mutually recursive definitions. In our case
  it could also start one line later (`rec jmp l2`). GHC then translates it into
  using `mfix` internally. (Using the deprecated `mdo` keyword instead of `rec`
  would make the code somewhat more natural.)
- We wrap the internals in the `X86` newtype. First it's always good to hide the
  internal implementation, it allows easy refactorings later. Second, `mfix`
  requires that the function passed to it `a -> m a` isn't strict in its
  argument. The effect must not depend on the argument, otherwise `mfix`
  diverges. This is condition is satisfied for our functions, but if the
  internals are exposed, someone could define a contrived function like this:

  ```
  -- | Reset the counter to the specified label.
  evilReset :: Label -> X86 ()
  evilReset = X86 . put . read . drop 5 . getLabel
  ```

  Not only it breaks the uniqueness of labels, but also causes the following code
  to hang:

  ```
  diverge :: X86 ()
  diverge = do
      rec evilReset l2
          l2 <- label
      return ()
  ```

---

Another quite similar alternative would be to use the
[`Rand`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/MonadRandom-0.5.1/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Random-Lazy.html)
monad and generate labels with the
[`Random`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/random-1.1/docs/System-Random.html#t:Random)
instance of
[`UUID`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/uuid-1.3.13/docs/Data-UUID.html#t:UUID).
Something like `WriterT String Rand a`, which also has a `MonadFix` instance.

---

(From purely academic perspective it might be possible to construct an arrow instead of a monad, that'd implement
[`ArrowLoop`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Control-Arrow.html#t:ArrowLoop),
but disallow state modifications that depend on values, such as in `evilReset`. But encapsulation of `X86` achieves the same goal, keeping the much friendlier `do` syntax.)